# How can I achieve the following in sed?

Tags: sed

The original text is:

```
apr_array_pstrcat(anythingbutalwayshereincludingspaces,anythingbutalwayshereincludingspaces, ',')
```

I want to change it to:

```
apr_array_pstrcat(samethingasabove,samethingasabove, ", ")
```

I got the following sed command, but it is not working:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/apr_array_pstrcat\((.*),(.*),(.*)','\)/apr_array_pstrcat\($1,$2,$3\", \"\)/g" {} +
```

How can I do this? I am able to understand PCRE regex, but I am not sure about this sed one.

Comment: Add `-E` after `-i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with OP's attempts:

- `-E` is needed to enable ERE, otherwise `\(` and `(` need to be reversed with default BRE
- `$1`, `$2`, etc should be `\1`, `\2`, etc
- there should be only two capture groups as per given sample
- also, `g` flag isn't needed if there can be only one match per line

```sh
sed -E "s/apr_array_pstrcat\((.*),(.*)','\)/apr_array_pstrcat\(\1,\2\", \"\)/g"
```

This can be simplified to:

```sh
sed -E "s/(apr_array_pstrcat\(.*),(.*)','\)/\1,\2\", \"\)/g"

# or this one, since using double quotes for entire expression can lead to
# conflict with shell double quote interpretation
sed -E 's/(apr_array_pstrcat\(.*),(.*)\x27,\x27\)/\1,\2", "\)/g'
```

This can be further simplified depending on what kind of data is present in the input:

```sh
# change ',' to ", " if a line contains apr_array_pstrcat(
sed '/apr_array_pstrcat(/ s/\x27,\x27/", "/'
```

Comment: I am using it with the find command. Please create your sed command including the find command. That might be the issue?

Comment: Full command is: `find . -type f -exec sed -iE 's/(apr_array_pstrcat\(.*),(.*)\x27,\x27\)/\1,\2", "\)/g' {} +`

Comment: you need to use `-i -E` not `-iE` .... also please experiment on a copy of your data

Comment: Yes, I am experimenting on a copy.

Comment: Also, how can I change `apr_array_pstrcat(anythingbutalwayshereincludingspaces,anythingbutalwayshereincludingspaces, 'anythinghere')` to `apr_array_pstrcat(samethingasabove,samethingasabove, "samethingasabove")`, so convert the single quotes there to double quotes.

Comment: use `([^\x27]*)` instead of `,` in the search regex and `"\3"` in replacement

Comment: So, the full command would be: `find . -type f -exec sed -iE 's/(apr_array_pstrcat\(.*),(.*)\x27([^\x27]*)\x27\)/\1,\2"\3"\)/g' {} +` ? Right?

Comment: yeah, except that it should be `-i -E` (space is important)

Comment: Oops, again I accidentally entered then -iE since I copied my old comment

Comment: Right. `find . -type f -exec sed -i -E 's/(apr_array_pstrcat\(.*),(.*)\x27([^\x27]*)\x27\)/\1,\2"\3"\)/g' {} +`

Answer (score 0):

sed has the -E flag for "use extended regular expressions in the script".

I'd also match the arguments with 'anything that's not a comma': "[^,]+"

So this works for me:

```
sed -E "s/(apr_array_pstrcat\([^,]+, [^,]+,) ','\)/\1 \", \")/"
```